# Minor issue in using dictionary and isspace function

Tags: python, whitespace, ordereddictionary

Here is my code for a simple Caesar's cipher-style program.

It works fine otherwise, but it does not recognize potential spaces between words written by the user.

While the program translates the letters themselves correctly, it prints all characters clustered together in a single word, omitting spaces.

I tried to solve this myself, but instead the program writes an error code:
"`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'isspace'`".

Is there another way?

```
key = {'a':'n', 'b':'o', 'c':'p', 'd':'q', 'e':'r', 'f':'s', 'g':'t',
       'h':'u', 'i':'v', 'j':'w', 'k':'x', 'l':'y', 'm':'z', 'n':'a',
       'o':'b', 'p':'c', 'q':'d', 'r':'e', 's':'f', 't':'g', 'u':'h',
       'v':'i', 'w':'j', 'x':'k', 'y':'l', 'z':'m', 'A':'N', 'B':'O',
       'C':'P', 'D':'Q', 'E':'R', 'F':'S', 'G':'T', 'H':'U', 'I':'V',
       'J':'W', 'K':'X', 'L':'Y', 'M':'Z', 'N':'A', 'O':'B', 'P':'C',
       'Q':'D', 'R':'E', 'S':'F', 'T':'G', 'U':'H', 'V':'I', 'W':'J',
       'X':'K', 'Y':'L', 'Z':'M'}


def change(message, new_message):

    for ch in message:
        if ch in key:
            new_message += key[ch]
        if ch in key.isspace():
            new_message += " "
    return new_message

def main():

    print 
    message = input("Type your message here.\n")
    new_message = ""
    print(change(message, new_message))

main()
```

Comment: What do you expect `if ch in key.isspace():` to do?

Comment: `key` is your dictionary, and `isspace()` is a function for string or character class. Therefore, you shouldn't use `ch in key.isspace()` but just `ch.isspace()`

Comment: You could easily also add a single space to your `key` dict. (It would map to a single space.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the line `if ch in key.isspace():` to `if ch.isspace():`

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking there would be a simple way to "bypass" the dictionary part, but I'm still new to the dictionary stuff as of now.